# Display error message on group of inputs AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, validation, accordion

I'm using 4 accordions on an page using AngularJS that houses 6 inputs each. There are single inputs as well. When the accordion is collapsed only the first input field is displayed. There is validation on the fields in the accordion.  The problem I'm having is that if there is an error on an input field that is hidden because the accordion is collapsed, the user will never know. I want to display an error that displays above the accordion. Does Angular offer something that detects an error in a group of input fields without having to check every input field? i.e.

```
<div ng-show="formname.submitted || formname.input1.$touched || formname.input2.$touched || etc">
    <span class="error">issues</span>                                                                              
</div>
```

Comment: You could put each group of inputs into its own form element.

Comment: That's what I was wondering...if there could be more than one form element but wasn't sure if that was best practice or not.

Comment: its not worst practice:) I have used this approach before. Each form will then exist on the scope and can have its own dirty and valid flag that you can check and show messages for.

Comment: Thanks @jw56578! Just one more question.It looks like I will still have to list each input in the accordion with $touched. Without this, the error will display when the page loads. Is it possible to use something like:
`<div ng-show="formname.submitted || formname.$touched>
    <span class="error">issues</span> ` 
or something similar?                                                                           
</div>

Comment: The form isn't going to have $touched, it will have $pristine. You should be able to use that in the way you want. It will be true if the user has not interacted with any of the input fields.